# Groovy: How to make script that read node name and based on that sends email notifications to different person

Tags: groovy, jenkins

Ok so i have one test job in jenkins that works on 5-6 nodes. So what i need is to make script that will read the node name and based on that send notification emails to different people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start create mailing list variables that contain your slave label and "*" after name (SLAVE1* and u can create it like this also SLAVE1_SLAVE2_...)

```
import hudson.model.*
import javax.mail.Message
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress

def envMap = build.getEnvironment(listener)
def NODE_NAME = envMap?.NODE_NAME
def NODE_ADDR_LIST = envMap.find{ it.key.contains(NODE_NAME  + "_") }.value

listener.getLogger().println("Found adresses for node " + NODE_NAME + "  -  " + NODE_ADDR_LIST);

NODE_ADDR_LIST.split(',').each{ msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(it + "@example.com")) }
```